# How to Show the not selected items in the MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need your help , right now i am working on code-ignite PHP Frame work

I have struck ed on the bellow logic implementation how to implement this plz tell me

Table

```
id  uname category

1    x     a

2    y     b

3    x     b

4    y     c

5    z     c
```

category column having only 3 a or b or c every user select 3 categories ,
i need to show like this

```
uname  category 

x       c

y       a

z       a

z       b
```

means user not selected categories i will be show on the table,plz tell how to implement this ..........

Comment: plz if you know tell i am waiting for your answers........

Comment: You've tagged this for both Oracle and MySQL.  Which are you really using?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: i need mysql yar ...............

Comment: i don't even know what you're asking

Comment: means you want like, suppose x user category like a,b,c but not double right?

Comment: reena shirale i want x user have a category i will show to admin panel b,c (it is not selected by x user).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print this on the Page , you can do like this:

```
$allCategories = array(a, b, c);    
$unames = "select uname from table_name group by uname;"
foreach ($unames as $uname) {
    $haveCategories = "select category from table_name  where uname = $uname group by category";
    $noCategories = array_diff($allCategories, $haveCategories); 
    foreach($noCategories as $category) {
        echo "$uname    $category\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: $categories where you declared this

Comment: if you want to improve the performance， you can select all the data once ,and processing in memory.